# How to add zero padding to an image?

Tags: image-processing

Consider an image (`img`) as

[image]

The dimension of the image is:

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img]
```

> {488, 275}

I want to change the dimension to the `power of 2`, which comes very next to the highest dimension `(488)` i.e. 512.

How can I do this?

**Edit 1:**

I am manually trying to do this using

```
Image[ArrayPad[ImageData[img], {a, b}]]
```

But cannot figure out the suitable values for `a` and `b`.

Comment: Try ImageResize

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't want to resize the image because it will distort the shape of the different features.

Comment: Ok! `ImageCrop[img]` gives an image of size 255x259 (nearby 256)

Comment: ... `ImageCrop[img,{256,256}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the image dimensions and calculate the log with base 2. Then take the `Ceiling` to get the next best exponent that is large or equal to it and use `ImageCrop`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzWZx.png"]
ImageCrop[img, 2^(Ceiling[Log[2, #]] & /@ ImageDimensions[img])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

There is an inbuilt function `ImagePad` to do this.

Firstly,

```
{wdesired, hdesired} = 2^Ceiling[Log[2, #]] & /@ ImageDimensions[img]
```

(Thanks to @halirutan)

This will give me the desired dimensions.

Now,

```
ImagePad[img, {{Ceiling[(wdesired - w)/2], 
   Floor[(wdesired - w)/2]}, {Ceiling[(hdesired - h)/2], 
   Floor[(hdesired - h)/2]}}]
```

gives me my desired image.